# Dynamically add form input fields with jquery .html()

Tags: jquery, post

I'm trying to dynamically add fields to my page and form.  Essentially what I have is a model container with a row of input fields. However any input field generated from the model container and appended inside the form is not posted.  See below.

```
$('#addRow').click(function () {
    var rowNumber = $(this).attr('rowNumber'),
        newRowHtml = '';

    rowNumber = parseInt(rowNumber) + 1;

    newRowHtml = '<tr id="row_' + rowNumber + '"> ' + $('#rowModel').html().replace(/myKeyHolder/g, rowNumber); + '</tr>';

    $('#row_' + parseInt(rowNumber - 1)).after(newRowHtml);
    $(this).attr('rowNumber', rowNumber);
});
```

EDIT: (Note using struts)

```
<tr id="rowModel" class="hide">
    <td>
        <s:select name="variable_myKeyHolder" 
                list="variables" listKey="value" listValue="label"
                cssClass="adminDropDown adminVariable" 
                data-role="dropdownlist"
                headerKey=""
                headerValue="Select Variable.." />
    </td>   
    <td>
        <select name="variableValue_myKeyHolder" id="variableValue_myKeyHolder" 
                class="adminDropDown adminVariableValue">                    
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <s:select name="variableType_myKeyHolder" 
            list="types" listKey="value" listValue="label"
            cssClass="adminDropDown adminVariableType" 
            data-role="dropdownlist" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <textarea name="message_myKeyHolder" class=messageTextarea">
        </textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Delete" class="deleteRequestMessage" id="btn_row_myKeyHolder">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: html model added. The form is surrounding the table

Comment: I dont see any `<tr>` with ID's beginning with `row`..

Comment: I didn't include them.  The rows are appended properly and function as designed.

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing the issue...what exactly is the isuse
?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on jsfiddle.net? It's easier to diagnose that way.

Comment: I set up some of it http://jsfiddle.net/LJbhm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem.  I am setting the value of the dropdowns through another function and the values of the dropdown options were not being set causing the data not to be posted.